# What is a good gentle introduction to the Virasoro algebra and its application in theoretical physics?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, mathematical-physics, string-theory

I am looking for an as gentle and pedagogical as possible introduction that explains the Virasoro algebra and its applications in theoretical physics; finally I am interested in its application in string theory.

The short explanations in the physics books I am reading are not enough to make me feel comfortable about the Virasoro algebra so I need to read some more ...

I prefer shorter than whole book references which are optimally freely accessible, but if this does not work other things are welcome too.

I know a little bit about Lie algebras and conformal transformations, but the central extension issue confuses me. What I am looking for could be something at the level of [these](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201124/) BRST lecture notes I could mostly follow.

Comment: The V. Algebra is a central extension of a Lie algebra of conformal complex transformations. As simple as you'd like it it is going to require full, or close to full undergraduate algebra (or even beyond), complex analysis and stuff....so odds are it is not going to be very gentle, and much even less if you want the applications to String Theory. Perhaps the best to do with this is to approach someone who masters the subject and learn directly from him.

Comment: @DonAntonio I know a little bit about Lie algebras and conformal transformations, but exactly this central extension confuses me. What I am looking for could be something at the level of [these](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201124/) BRST lecture notes I could mostly follow. I have not the possibility to aske somebody ind the "real world", and I can neither ask this at physics SE because there any reference / study material questions get immediately closed since some months ... :-/

Comment: @Dilaton Central extensions aren't really very hard to understand.  They're a lot like direct products, but instead of keeping them completely separated, you allow isomorphic central subgroups of each group to overlap.  You should search around for some explanations of central products - they are not difficult, just uncommon.

Comment: Thanks for this hint @AlexanderGruber, so I will poke around a bit for central procuducts here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice and friendly [user](http://www.quora.com/Jitendra-Prakash) at Quora has pointed out [these](http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1287) lecture notes to me.

I have not jet fully read it, but is seems very useful to me and obviously explains some additional things I am missing.

Comment: Some more sources (they are actually on string theory, but that clearly means they talk a lot about (super-)virasoro algebra and its applications in physics (specifically string theory) and as a quantisation of Witt Algebra, which is isomorphic to Conformal http://math.berkeley.edu/~kwray/papers/string_theory.pdf (AN INTRODUCTION TO STRING THEORY),  http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0207249v1.pdf (Introduction to String Theory), http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0207142v1.pdf (BUSTEPP LECTURES ON STRING THEORY)

Comment: Thanks @dimension10 I will look into these too, and the application in ST is what picks me too :-). Too bad, that such questions can no longer be posted on physics SE, where they would fit better. But David Zaslasky would have pounced on it faster than the speed of light and closed it, as soon as he would have seen it if I had tried it at physics SE :-(. So for reference questions on can only ask them here where the moderation is less political and much more reasonable. The drawback of this approach is that such questions get low attention here, because would be better served at physics ...

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS I have [big troubles](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2751/dilaton), you can read on TRF why ...

Comment: What?! 4 months?! And *David Zaslavasky* did that.?, Ok, I'll put that TRF discussion link there .      But first, I need to cut 225 characters some how...

Comment: P.S. Do you intend to return to Physics.SE after the suspension period? Hope you do.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS I still think that it is important that there are reasonable people who kick wrongly close voted, questions out of the close queue, try to reopen wrongly closed questions, close and downvote bad low-level stuff and upvote the not enough appreciated higher level technical content, etc so I'd like to see you reach the 3000 soon! I personally will wait what Shog9 says, when he promised to look into something he always did so at least, even if the outcome may more or less deviate from what I expect ...

Comment: I am sometimes not quite sure, if it would be more "constructive" (tongue in cheek) to put the available time and motivation I have completely in starting a Physics Overflow, as under the current completely rigid boundery contidions Physics SE can not be saved and become a nice higher-level academic in spirit site again, there might be a point to give up on it for me at some time, but I am not yet sure. Have to cool down (but not 4 months) and think rationally about it ...