# Grasping the idea of Virasoro Algebras in 2D Conformal field theory

Tags: lie-algebras, mathematical-physics, string-theory, conformal-field-theory

I have been trying to understand the connection between Virasoro algebras and CFT. After a course in string theory, I was under the impression that the Virasoro algebra was simply the Lie algebra of the conformal group, but that is not the case. I would like to get an overview of what is going on, since right now I do not have time to go into the details, but would still like to have a bird's eye view of the topic.

This is what seems to me so far, trying to translate physicists' lingo to maths (in the context of CFT in the euclidean plane):

1. The conformal group is the group of global conformal transformations $\mathbb{R}^{2,0}\to \mathbb{R}^{2,0}$.
2. The Lie algebra of the conformal group is finite-dimensional.
3. For each $x\in \mathbb{R}^{2,0}$, we have an algebra of "infinitesimal conformal transformations" (which I believe can be interpreted as conformal Killing fields) defined in a neighborhood of $x$, which is the Witt algebra. This is infinite-dimensional.
4. The conformal Killing fields generate the *local* conformal transformations $U\to U'$.

So it seems that locally we get Virasoro algebras of Killing fields, and these generate local conformal transformations, *even though there is no Lie group whose Lie algebra is the Virasoro algebra*.

How far off am I?

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12022

Comment: Have a look, for example, at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350281/what-is-a-good-gentle-introduction-to-the-virasoro-algebra-and-its-application-i). The answer has some nice references.  Actually, for $2$-dimensional CFT you'll need $\mathcal{W}$-algebras, so a central extension of the Virasoro algebra. For details see for example [here](https://www.itp.uni-hannover.de/~flohr/papers/w-talk.pdf).